# dismiss Keyboard not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Hi, I am not able to dismiss keyboard. I have a scroll view which have **UITextFields** on a it. I tried using

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

And

```
[self.scrollView endEditing:YES];
```

I tried using **resignFirstResponder** on individual textfields but no use.

This issue only occurs when I tap a textfield which I am using as button when taped upon it I use

`[textField resignFirstResponder];`

but old one don't resign whatever I do like I tried using endEditing before I resigned the button like textfield. So my question is what could be the problem in my scenario and is there any way to forcefully dismiss keyboard?

Comment: For resignFirstResponder.. have you set the delegate for your textfield?

Comment: What triggers the method that calls `[textField resignFirstResponder];`?

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField triggers the method to resign keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want textField to act as button, use delegates.

```
textField.delegate=self;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: My problem was that i was using - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField to resign the button like textfield that was casing the old to not to dismiss. using textFieldShouldBeginEditing solved this problem.